# Cannot cut layer selection in Mac VEntura 13.16 with GIMP 2.10.34 (rev3)

Tags: gimp

That's it.

- Select with magic wand, hit mac Backspace or Fn+Backspace for delete does nothing.
- Also cut is greyed out on the contextual menu after opening it from the selection.
- The correct layer is selected in the layer menu.
- The settings cannot register fn+delete as the shortcut for layer-deletion and it says disabled on the column of the shortcut/keybinding
- There's no floating selection.
- Also Command+X fills the selection with the current background color in the palette rather than showing the transparent layer ...
- It looks unusable from Mac.

My work around is to copy and paste the inverted selection to a New Layer... not great.

Answer (score 1):

1. The layer has no alpha channel, so cannot be transparent (layer nales of alpha-less layers is in boldface in the `Layers` list). Use `Layer  > Transparency > Add alpha channel` to allow it to be transparent(*).
2. The layer is also probably pixel-locked, just click the lock icon to unlock it.

[image]

(*) An alpha channel is not added by default when an image is imported from a a format that doesn't allow transparency, such as JPEG. This can be changed in  Preferences > Image Import & Export > Import policies`